# Global auto login not working correctly

Tags: support, auto-login

For whatever reason, logging into Board and Card Games no longer logs in me in automatically to other sites on the StackExchange network.

Specifically, the sites I tried were:

- Meta.Gaming (Gaming is blocked where I work)
- StackOverflow
- Programmers

In fact, logging in from any of these would not log me into the others.

The only site where auto-login worked was here on Meta.SO, and only when I logged in on SO first.

The browser in question is Firefox 3.6.12. This is what I get from the [Global Login Test page](https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help):

> Test 1: JavaScript – ok
>
> JavaScript is enabled – that's a good
>   start.
>
> Test 2: Cookies – ok
>
> Cookies are enabled; very good.
>
> Test 3: Messaging – ok
>
> Excellent, your browser supports the
>   HTML5 postMessage feature.
>
> Test 4: Storage – ok
>
> Your browser supports the HTML5 DOM
>   storage – great!
>
> Test 5: Communication with StackAuth –
>   ok
>
> IFRAMEs – ok
>
> Referrer – ok
>
> JavaScript – ok
>
> Storage – ok
>
> Perfect; this site is able to
>   communicate with StackAuth.
>
> All tests were successful
>
> All tests have passed; your browser is
>   well-equipped to log in.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your work is also blocking `stackauth.com` which would prevent global logins from working.

There are two pieces to this:

1. HTML 5 local storage, a local browser dependency
2. `stackauth.com`, a global internet dependency

We have a new diagnostic page for checking this:

https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help

Give that a shot and let me know what it says.

Comment: I wonder if it's worthwhile considering using something like auth.stackoverflow.com rather than a separate TLD.

Comment: I've gone to the network login help page and pasted its results above.  I also tried running it from boardgames.stackexchange.com with identical results.

Comment: @r.bemrose then it should be working

Comment: It appears that the issue has been resolved... possibly because I cleared my cookies... but if you go to a Meta site first (including Meta.SO), it will not auto-log you on until you click the "log in" link.  Which, on other metas redirects you to the main site, so I cannot log in to Meta.Gaming for the reasons stated above.

Comment: @r.bem ah, I'll add "clear cookies" to the "random things to try" on that page